# No consigo que admitan mi email al enviar correos

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, estoy intentando poder enviar mensajes de email a los usuarios.
Para hacer eso, debo configurar el fichero .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=pajaritosami88@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Tras eso, creo la función que enviara el mensaje a un determinado usuario:

```
public function mensajeActivar(User $usuario){
        Mail::to($usuario->email)->send(new Mensajeria($usuario->id));

        return back()->with('message',['success',"Se ha enviado al usuario un mensaje que redirige al código de activación"]);
    }
```

El fichero Mensajeria.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Mensajeria extends Mailable{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $numero;

    public function __construct($numero){
        $this->numero=$numero;
    }

    public function build(){
        return $this->view('activacion');
    }
}
```

El fichero activacion.blade.php:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Active su cuenta en Bolsa Empleo</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <p>Se ha registrado con exito.</p><br>
    <p>Pulse el siguiente enlace para activar su cuenta:</p><br>
    <a href='http://localhost/bolsa/public/activar/{{$numero}}'>Activar</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Pero tras esto, me topo con este mensaje de error:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v66sm16186852wmd.41 - gsmtp "
```

Se supone que tengo que habilitar mi cuenta para usarse con programas pocos seguros, pero no tengo muy claro el que se supone que debo hacer.

Comment: Hola tocayo, bueno tu problema es muy fácil de arreglar, cuando haces el uso de una cuenta gmail, automáticamente te llega un mensaje de advertencia que otra aplicación desea acceder a tu cuenta, ahí mismo en el correo te da las opciones para poderlo habilitar, aquí hay un link que te puede ayudar https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=es-419

Comment: @MiguelOsorio Pues gracias a tu consejo lo he logrado. Lo que me sangra de todo esto es tener que dar la contraseña de email dentro de mi proyecto.